Non-system disk after installing 24.04 on an old HP Elitebook
I installed 24.04.1 on an HP Elitebook 8530w with BIOS version circa 2009.

After what appeared to be a successful installation, I received the Non-system disk message at restart. The two partitions created on the internal solid state drive contained grub2 core.img, flagged bios_grub and ext4 with no flags.

What am I missing?
ADDED: Security Setting
UEFI Option

Check that your sdb disk is first in the boot order -- maybe you are trying to boot off sda?

Thanks. Definitely booting off the right drive.

I am making a lot of guesses. That rig seems to support secure boot. https://www.hp.com/hpinfo/newsroom/press_kits/2008/siggraph/ds_elitebook8530w_mobileworkstation.pdf You are hinting you have installed BIOS rather than UEFI mode. Possibly it has never had an MBR installed? What are the BIOS security settings? Alternatively install in UEFI mode.

I have added a screenshot of the BIOS security options in the OP. It looks like everything is turned off. I had tried installing in UEFI mode, but the boot up would halt at the BIOS splash screen. I have also added the UEFI option setting to the OP.

Did you actually install in UEFI mode -ie with secure boot enabled? Did you use the Desktop installer? As it stands, in legacy mode, it believe it will need a boot flag of some sort. Is there a second disk (sda)? When saying it halted at the BIOS splash you mean on the first boot after installation with secure boot enabled? That suggests it couldn't find anything to boot meaning grub was not installed in the UEFI partition.  Did the installation install a UEFI partition?

I did not install in UEFI mode. I could not because when I enabled EFI, the system wouldn’t boot past the BIOS splash screen with the USB install drive inserted.  Install documented in this post was a result of automatic install not in UEFI mode and with the security settings shown. There is only one drive in the laptop. The installation created the bios_grub partition, no UEFI partition.
